# Wifi adapter disappears after a while

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I'm using Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01) on HP Envy k212ne.
On fresh start the wifi works fine but after a while suddenly it does not until next reboot.

running **sudo iwconfig:**

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Saeed"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.447 GHz  Access Point: BC:34:00:42:64:60   
          Bit Rate:72 Mb/s   Tx-Power=200 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-40 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessiv
e retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

This tells me i'm connected, but i'm not and it's like it's freezed cause when i run it again same level and signal quality is shown. even when i run *sudo ifconfig wlo1 down* this still remains the same.

running **sudo dmesg:**

```
[ 3597.126863] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan :
[ 3597.126866] WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[ 3598.128222] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : 
[ 3598.128224] WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[ 2522.093255] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_disconnect : 
[ 2522.093257] error (-22)
```

running **nmcli dev:**

```
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION
eno1    ethernet  connected    Wired connection 1  
wlo1    wifi      unavailable  --  
lo      loopback  unmanaged    --
```

running **rfkill list:**
 In **ubuntu 20 LTS** it shows this:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**BUT in debian and mx linux there was no hard block.**

I tried:
`sudo rfkill unblock all`

I tried black listing hp_wmi to disable hard block entirely

this hard block was not a thing in ubuntu 18 LTS, debian, mx linux.

**What i've Tried:**

1. Installing other linux distros like mx linux using xfce and debian.
2. replacing network-manager with wicd.
3. unload and load, reinstall drivers.
4. blacklist conflicting drivers.
5. restart network-manager service.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 30 Apr 2020 20:42 +0430 +0430

Booted last: 30 Apr 2020 00:00 +0430 +0430

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.4.0-28-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 22 17:40:10 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Broadcom BCM43142 802.11bgn 1x1 WiFi Adapter + BT 4.0 combo adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:2230]

09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:229c]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0a5c:216c Broadcom Corp. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth Device
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 138a:0050 Validity Sensors, Inc. Swipe Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05c8:036e Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) Webcam
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

EFI variables are not supported on this system

##### lsmod #############################

wl                   6455296  0
cfg80211              704512  1 wl
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
wmi                    32768  2 hp_wmi,wmi_bmof

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>

##### iwconfig ##########################

eno1      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Saeed"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.447 GHz  Access Point: <MAC address>   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         804       1  0 19:10 ?        00:00:26 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
root        4603    4226  0 20:13 pts/2    00:00:00 sudo journalctl -fu NetworkManager
root        4604    4603  0 20:13 pts/2    00:00:00 journalctl -fu NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eno1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         40 (Carrier/link changed)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:09:00.0/net/eno1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlo1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         wl
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.30.223.271 (r587334)
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:08:00.0/net/wlo1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.MESH:                   no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.IBSS-RSN:               no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  IN-USE 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

cat: /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state: Permission denied

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-ubuntu-fan.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices+=interface-name:fan-*

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:docker0;interface-name:veth*;interface-name:br-*

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Marzi.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Marzi | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Marzi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Tehran (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

eno1      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlo1      32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)

##### iwlist scan #######################

wlo1      Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

eno1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-28-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     00D38A27B7E3C7B97C238FC
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           wl
vermagic:       5.4.0-28-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-28-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     8795FC14A499B3F7A2F6AD8
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.4.0-28-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        42:A8:A9:98:8B:E6:F1:71:2C:AF:A3:32:4E:72:D5:45:3C:41:3F:7A
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      5C:D8:AC:A2:FD:65:17:DB:37:3C:41:4F:49:45:94:86:F4:B3:EF:B0:
        6F:CF:F7:C7:27:AA:1A:4A:E8:AC:88:C7:BA:D6:71:B9:64:E4:08:16:
        33:A0:CB:BF:A7:A0:9F:33:14:66:1E:A9:61:42:72:50:04:85:79:8D:
        97:36:57:F4:45:04:2C:80:4D:B4:37:EE:D6:CC:A5:D0:43:95:0A:DC:
        AB:F2:13:D7:45:73:B8:85:CF:6B:0C:BA:FB:79:20:97:8F:AE:72:E9:
        18:0D:D6:64:2D:99:BB:62:A1:23:28:50:4B:B6:69:07:56:FE:F9:C5:
        99:78:95:94:A4:E0:79:36:27:DF:66:48:C4:D8:CF:86:29:12:5E:CF:
        CD:40:FF:DC:92:44:9A:1D:A5:57:08:81:5B:A0:0D:2D:42:35:30:0E:
        76:90:8F:D7:E6:8F:66:04:22:3E:CF:C3:99:4C:7B:F2:CE:8A:54:D6:
        83:45:EB:82:3A:CB:E4:26:E3:C8:73:97:06:C2:EB:71:A5:38:75:53:
        AC:5D:2E:DD:8B:68:DE:1C:F8:43:35:C2:B1:C5:E5:19:01:9B:F1:23:
        87:74:D0:64:50:AD:CE:AE:B4:D7:34:67:DB:40:1E:8F:12:D2:D5:E9:
        F7:B6:BD:0E:64:87:24:52:BC:00:15:33:04:08:00:E6:DE:42:54:AA:
        FC:BC:1D:BF:4F:6B:73:AD:77:F7:37:22:C0:C9:D6:A3:CA:D9:02:83:
        54:4B:DA:51:84:AD:84:3A:F8:34:27:79:42:E9:CD:4F:74:65:8C:F2:
        43:A5:26:6F:F1:20:B3:29:29:5C:C2:16:4C:ED:DB:EE:CD:B6:AD:5E:
        C0:E6:C0:54:4D:F9:A7:90:04:38:60:48:51:B2:CA:5D:7D:06:E4:44:
        71:29:C4:73:62:50:4C:30:D6:41:B5:B3:47:71:21:1E:A6:22:AB:19:
        9B:56:28:B1:FB:CD:77:0E:30:71:7B:AD:2C:BD:57:7E:9C:EF:42:75:
        4F:E3:17:44:15:FF:3E:0C:F9:AB:5A:3C:EB:DA:7C:42:41:6B:CE:A9:
        F0:7E:A5:1D:C4:64:7B:17:D9:51:5E:62:5E:7F:AF:D5:99:F3:AE:02:
        50:65:E7:7F:61:AF:54:9B:8D:EF:F0:A4:01:C6:51:84:AE:41:8D:F4:
        7F:E7:B1:C0:D3:E2:F2:BA:38:48:52:A0:FC:B4:BA:F8:0C:C1:BB:66:
        2D:D1:65:2B:A9:C6:2E:1D:D7:C5:90:61:D1:60:9D:54:B8:E9:7C:C2:
        1D:3B:D3:51:5B:CC:F7:92:2B:12:86:4C:EC:FB:BD:E7:E3:D5:1A:EC:
        9B:BA:C5:AA:2A:31:0D:73:AD:56:BA:77
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[ 1524.384479] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eno1: Link is Down
[ 1606.391024] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eno1: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[ 1606.391048] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eno1: link becomes ready
[ 1885.273890] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eno1: Link is Down
[ 1897.998620] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eno1: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[ 3685.055608] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : 
[ 4026.605757] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eno1: Link is Down
[ 4117.418475] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eno1: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[ 4124.185220] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eno1: Link is Down
[ 4128.494878] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : 
[ 4370.103487] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eno1: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[ 4392.969612] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eno1: Link is Down
[ 4570.331043] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : 

########## wireless info END ############
```

thanks for your time and help.